# Xamarin Android - Securing API Keys using Android NDK

Tags: c#, android, security, xamarin.android, android-ndk

There is a great article written here

https://medium.com/@abhi007tyagi/storing-api-keys-using-android-ndk-6abb0adcadad

about storing sensitive api secrets as secure as possible.

I am working with Xamarin.Android. Unfortunately I am struggeling adapting this concept to Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin.Android and google didn't help me either.

Does someone know how i can achieve this in Xamarin C#? Thank you very much for help in advance.

Comment: Note that you add very little security in this way. It's really just an extra step or two for people to find your strings.

Comment: I think this is a horrible article.  Reverse engineering that small of a .so file is probably easier than finding the string in a large obfuscated Java app.

Comment: @GabeSechan totally disagree. can you argue your arguments anyway?

Comment: @Michael ye this is about putting extra steps on extra steps.

Comment: @Andreas Because it provides no additional security, decompiling a simple so library is trivial (I'd have your key in under 5 minutes-  it would actually take me longer in pure Java code because there's more of it to dig through) and increases your complexity for no gain.  Now if you want actual security, provide your API keys from a server that requires a login to gain access.  Then they aren't in your apk at all.  But you gain nothing but a false sense of having done something from this technique.  Its bad even by the low bar of medium posts.

Comment: @Gabe Secha. Putting the key on the server and deliver it via secured webapi does not change much i think. Because then u just shift the security to the login part. When someone knows the login he has access to the api key. The only solution would be not returning the api key from the server. But this is sometimes not possible from design

Comment: @Andreas It changes a ton, if you don't understand that you don't understand security.  It means the api key isn't in your APK at all. So in order to even attempt to capture it, they need a login to your app, and capture it in memory after its downloaded in the running app.  Much more difficult.  Even more secure is to have the server make any calls and pass the results to the client so the client never gets the key, but that can be expensive in servers.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan. I agree on the part where the client never gets the key. But when u return they api key in the request of your secured web api. One can reverse engeneer the login credentials and your api endpoint. Then just write his own client tool which pretent to be yours and gets the api key.

Comment: @Andreas They could.  Anything you send to a client can potentially be compromised, they only way to assure its safety is to never put it on a device you don't physically control.  But if you're looking for things less than total security that puts a speedbump up, getting it from the server is an order of magnitude better than keeping it in the client and putting it in a .so file.

Comment: @GabeSechan ok thx for advice! I think I need to take a closer look at this topic. For understanding what I have right now. The login credentials would be exposed to the same threat as the api key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[PInvoke](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/)** in Xamarin as normal if you want to call native code from your C# code. You can read more about it in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries).

But as pointed out in the comments, it wouldn't really improve the security of your app, unless you have a big native library with encrypted string literals and force-inlined functions that deal with them.

**Edit:** Why it is easy to reverse engineer small binary

Consider the following C++ code (**test.cpp**):

```
#define GET_KEY(n)                \
const char *GetKey##n()           \
{                                 \
   const char * key = "mykey" #n; \
   return key;                    \
}

GET_KEY(1)
GET_KEY(2)
GET_KEY(3)
GET_KEY(4)
GET_KEY(5)
GET_KEY(6)
GET_KEY(7)
GET_KEY(8)
GET_KEY(9)
```

Now I compile it with `clang++ -shared -o test.so test.cpp` and view the resulting **test.so** in a hex editor. Among other hex data I can find the following line there:

```
mykey1<0x00>mykey2<0x00>mykey3<0x00>mykey4<0x00>mykey5<0x00>mykey6<0x00>mykey7<0x00>mykey8<0x00>mykey9<0x00>
```

Most of the other content is hex data or some well-known symbols so it's not too difficult to spot that string for one who knows what he is looking for.

Comment: mb then it would make sense to grab a random "big" native library and extract the keys from them?

Comment: I think it makes sense but I'm not an expert in this area and I don't know what industry standard is in such cases. The problem with small libraries is that all string literals are placed in the same region in the binary so if they are few and all of them are your keys it's quite easy to find them. Personally I'd just rewrite some parts of logic in C++ and then use compile-time encryption and runtime decryption for the keys, and inline all functions that verify them.